# Python - How to pass value of var outside of class

Tags: python

I'm trying to workout how to pass the value of the variable `price_val` from the class to another function outside of the class

```
class TextWebsocketClient(cbpro.WebsocketClient):
    def on_open(self):
        self.url           = 'wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com'
        self.message_count = 0
    
    def on_message(self,msg):
        self.message_count += 1
        msg_type = msg.get('type',None)
        if msg_type == 'ticker':
            time_val   = msg.get('time',('-'*27))
            price_val  = msg.get('price',None)
            if price_val is not None:
                price_val = float(price_val)
            product_id = msg.get('product_id',None)
            outFile = open('sample.txt', 'a')
            outFile.write(f"{time_val:30} \
                {price_val:.3f} \
                {product_id}\tchannel type:{msg_type}\n")
            outFile.close()
            #print(f"{time_val:30} \
            #    {price_val:.3f} \
            #    {product_id}\tchannel type:{msg_type}")

    
    def on_close(self):
        print(f"<---Websocket connection closed--->\n\tTotal messages: {self.message_count}")
```

I want to take the value of var and compare the value against the previous value to print if the value has gone up or down.

Thanks

Comment: Store it as `self.previous_val = var`?

Comment: What other function do you have in mind? You have shown how `price_val` is generated, but not what happens to it.

Comment: Thanks Robin - where would i store this? would this be inside of the class? How would i then pass this value outside of the class?

Comment: Hi Quamrana, the price_val is printed when i run ```stream = TextWebsocketClient(products=['BTC-USD'],channels=['ticker'])```
Once i've got the latest price, i need to pass this value further into the program which i will then compare previous with current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class TextWebsocketClient():
    ...
    
    def on_message(self):
        ...
        price_val = "Hi"
        outside_func(price_val)

    ...

def outside_func(price_val):
    print(price_val)
```

I know this method only)

Comment: Thanks Akbar, that works, but i don't understand why that works. :( I need to learn more